# Regarding Axioms that Preserve Order

Tags: analysis

I have a general question about the axioms for ordered fields regarding addition and multiplication preserving order. I'm relatively new to pure-math and analysis style courses, but the style in those courses seems to vary from allowing me to assume basis arithmetic while others won't. For example, if I have a + (-a) = 0, one course would allow me to multiply both sides by some field element (say, b), whereas another would force me to prove that's a valid operation; the same is true with adding some element, say the inverse of that element a, to both sides.

In particular, working through Ross, he presents the cancellation law (ab = ac implies that b = c provided that a is non-zero) as a consequence of the field properties. But say that I have b^-1 = a^-1 (in particular, I'm doing this by assumption for some other proof in order to find a contradiction). Then I have two other elements, a and b, that I know to be non-zero. Solutions to this problem I've found suggest multiplying both sides by ab (finding that a = b, a contradiction). I understand why this would be the case, but what I really question is what would allow him to do this. Is there some theorem I'm missing that makes this a valid step, or should I simply assume that basic arithmetic operations are valid by the definitions of a field?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A careful reading of the textbook (which I can't do, since I don't have it) should make it clear what you can/can't assume at each stage. If not, ask your instructor for her advice.

Comment: To be clear, your question in your example is why $x=y$ implies $xz=yz$?

Comment: After thinking about this some more, yes, I think that is essentially my question. It sounds like the cancellation law in reverse (for non-zero x and y), which I would think might follow from standard arithmetic. Another theorem states that if I have x <= y and some z >= 0, then xy <= yz. I suppose my question is how I might amend this theorem to eliminate the 'equals' option. (Or do I prove xy <= yz and then write a lemma to establish by contradiction that they can't be equal? I believe this was the approach I took in a past course.)